# Missing link in the German tank development?

Tags: military, germany, tanks, argentina

As you know, the Leopard 1 was not the first tank of postwar Germany. Germany work on different new tanks. There are prototypes as medium tank *Indienpanzer* (later developed into a Swiss *KW30* and its successors *Pz.58* and *Pz.61*), light tank *RU 251 Prototype SpPz mit 90mm BK*, early prototypes of the *Leopard-1* MBT. On some forums I've seen mention about a strange **Argentinapanzer** - stage between Indienpanzer and prototypes of Leopard-1. However, I have been unable to find the details about this tank. It's definitely not a TAM, *TanqueArgentinoMediano* is subsequent and is not related to the Leopard-1.

Theory looks pretty good, after all, Germany and Argentina were close military-technical cooperation.

**Does anyone know about Argentinapanzer, a german prototype tank for Argentina from the 1950s?**

Answer (score 2):

German wikipedia mentions nothing of an Argentine project predating Leopard 1 development. The Indienpanzer project and its failure is mentioned briefly, together with a statement that at the time German industry was incapable of developing a modern MBT, that the failed India project gave German industry and especially Porsche the knowledge needed to make Leopard 1 work.
I don't have my reference material here, but vaguely recall another abandoned German tank development project for a south American country from the 1980s, a cheaper, smaller, alternative to Leopard 2 (and a competitor to the AMX-40 which was being developed by the French for the export market). Maybe that's the one you're looking for?

Comment: Wiki mentions nothing of RU 251 Prototype SpPz mit 90mm BK too. But this is real tank :) [Photo](http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/4208/valiant-17.196/0_48b31_9d65ba6d_L)